# Save Data: JSON or Database?

Tags: json, database

In a html/css/js browser game I'm making, I have determined I will eventually need to have saving functions. I've used database save data before, but my other coding friends recommended using JSON. Which method is better? more efficient? easier?

Only a few strings and mostly small integers are being saved. Some Object-oriented programming is used.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your choice will depend on how much you care about the users having access to the save data and also really what the game is in the first place.

json or xml for that matter are nice save formats that you can dump all the info into and easily read it back later. But if you are saving it on the local machine the user obviously has access to it.

Also storing stuff locally like that means you don't rely on network anything which is always good unless your game already relies on the network.

If you have any online play local save data is obviously bad in most cases.
Against it really depends on what your game is doing.

Finally it's much faster to get something up in running that uses local saves. And is one less thing to worry about the users having network issues because of proxys or whatever that prevent them from getting their save data.

I would say local storage with json/xml is more efficient/easier. But the downside is it is less safe and prone to the being accidentally deleted/corrupted (which is why many steam games have local saves but also cloud backup).

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no los dos?
Are you looking for local saves or cloud saves? For local saves, use IndexedDB.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

You can store JSON documents in it.

For cloud saves, use a natively supported JSON store like MongoDB or CouchDB. CouchDB is a nice option for exposing a JSON store directly to the WAN with minimal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Object Notation (http://www.json.org/) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is NOT a format for storing data! Use JSON to communicate data between your server and client but store the data in properly designed tables in one of many, many databases available out there. If you have some strings and integers, just create a simple table. Storing JSON as strings in a database is sacrilege!

Comment: Caveat: There are situations where storing serialized data makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is misleading. Yes, JSON is an interchange format. (It's also encodes a valid JavaScript expression, which is its raison d'etre.) But storing in tables versus storing strings is a false choice.
Users in the OP's position are trying to store documents. SQL doesn't have a strong concept of document hierarchy - that need is implemented indirectly with foreign keys and application logic.
A NoSQL store that accepts and retrieves JSON is a good solution in this case, especially when the application is JS-based. That doesn't mean the DB is storing a JSON string under the hood.